# Recommend resources of Abstract Algebra which contain more historical development

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request

I read the Wikipedia page about [Abstract Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_algebra). There is a sentence that says

> Numerous textbooks in abstract algebra start with axiomatic
>   definitions of various algebraic structures and then proceed to
>   establish their properties. This creates a false impression that in
>   algebra axioms had come first and then served as a motivation and as a
>   basis of further study.

This exactly expressed my feelings about algebra. I am majored in physics, I learned knowledge of algebra which I need from wikipedia and books, but not systematically. They all state algebra in axiom style. I admit the definition of algebraic structure is very delicate and the logical deduction of the axioms are unexpected rich. So I admired that mathematicians can construct so abstract axioms which at the first sight not relevant to real world problem, yet the result is so useful and universal. But the mathematicians surely motivated by various specific problems.

The wikipedia link above gives some examples:

1. Solving of systems of linear equations led to linear algebra
2. Attempts to find formulae for solutions of general polynomial equations of higher degree that resulted in discovery of groups as abstract manifestations of symmetry
3. Arithmetical investigations of quadratic and higher degree forms and diophantine equations, that directly produced the notions of a ring and ideal.
4. the hypercomplex numbers of the nineteenth century had kinematic and physical motivations but challenged comprehension.

**So can someone recommend books or resources which have a good account on the historical development of the concept of abstract algebra step by step?**

Comment: Why don't search with google for History of abstract algebra? This way you can find http://www.amazon.com/History-Abstract-Algebra-Israel-Kleiner/dp/0817646841

Comment: Kleiner's History of Algebra is quite good.